# How to simulate sample sizes so that the standard error of the mean difference between two groups has a uniform distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, simulation, standard-error, meta-analysis

I want to simulate fictional studies to illustrate some aspects of a meta-analysis. My simulation setup is simple: All studies compare two independent groups drawn from normal distributions with equal standard deviations and a fixed mean difference of $\delta$. I want to vary the sample size for each simulated study. For a single comparison, $D=\bar{X_1}-\bar{X_2}$ is the raw mean difference between the samples. Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be the sample standard deviations of the two groups and $n_1$ and $n_2$ be the sample size in the two groups. Assuming $n_1 = n_2=n$, the variance of $D$, assuming equal population standard deviations is:
$$
v_D=\frac{1}{n}(S_1^2+S_2^2)
$$
The standard error is simply $\sqrt{v_D}$.

**My question:** How do I have to sample the sample sizes $n$ so that the standard errors $\sqrt{v_D}$ have a uniform distribution (roughly)?

Comment: 1. Do you care about the parameters of this desired uniform? 2. You may need a pretty loose sense of 'roughly'.

Comment: @Glen_b I don't think I care about the parameters. I would like to fix the sample sizes to be in a (semi)realistic range, between 10 and 2500, say.

Comment: For a sense of how hard this is going to be, consider that the gamma distributions for the variance estimate at different $n$ should have the same mean but different shapes and spreads; all will be right-skew and the more spread out components will be more skew. If we could move the mean about, I think you could get something sort of satisfactory, but with fixed mean, a very narrow range of $n$ for some large $n$ (i.e. a roughly normal distribution) is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: @Glen_b That's already very helpful, thank you. Since this is just an illustration, I have no problem of accepting that it is probably futile to pursue this further.